# Salesforce - Notification when too many records are recorded in a day

Tags: notifications, salesforce, alert

In Salesforce, is there a way to send notification when too many records are created on an object in a day?

- The notification can be via email, chatter or any other method.
- "Too many records" - we have not defined yet what "too many" means. So, let's assume it is 2 (the actual number will end up being much higher than this).

There is no other criteria than the fact that the records are created. So, we are not checking for values in specific fields.

I have tried creating reports/dashboard. But have not found a way to create the alert based on the number of records reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a report on records created today / yesterday. After saving you'll have an option to subscribe to it / schedule it. On that screen you can add extra send criteria such as only if *row count > X*.

There used to be something about sending Chatter posts when gauge charts met criteria (think "sales team closed 2M in deals, woohoo!" but I can't find any documentation, you might have to experiment.

Comment: thank you for that suggestion. This solution works for our reqiurements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Event Monitor can do this in Salesforce.

Otherwise, you'd need to count records created by day, and then determine your threshold. I would look at how many records have been created a day historically over the last 3-6 months, lets say an average of 1,000.

Then add 20%, I'd want to know about any day that went to 1,200.

You can probbably do this with a screenflow, you can definitely do it with Apex.

Comment: I don't see anything around record creates in event monitoring / transaction security? And event monitoring is paid add-on... If the config options don't cut it I'd rather create a stupid scheduled job and plug apex there than pay for event monitoring just so I can run my custom transaction security plugin :/